# Upload Same File by doing it once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

Goal:
When I select a file in name="file" I would like to make a copy of it to name="file2" automatically.  In the end, you upload to same file by doing it once.

Problem:
I have made some research and today I cannot find an answer to my question.

```
<input name="file" type="file" accept=".xml, .txt" />

<input name="file2" type="file" accept=".xml, .txt" hidden />
```

Comment: Your description of what you're trying to do makes no sense. Also, you have very little control over file inputs for security reasons, and the `hidden` attribute is not valid on them.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to duplicate it on the server after it's been uploaded, and save on network traffic?

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to duplicate the file?

Comment: James- it doesn't work based on your message due to complex situation. It is a long story. I really mean L-O-N-G story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
$("#file1id").change(function (){
  if($('#file2id').length){
     $('#file2id').remove();
  }
  $(this).clone().attr('id', 'file2id').attr('type', 'hidden').insertAfter($(this));
});
```

Working on [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ayd4x079/)

EDIT: Sorry, I have forgotten to fork Jsfiddle's link. Then it's too hard for me.

Comment: _"Working on Jsfiddle"_ - [No it's not](https://jsfiddle.net/ayd4x079/1/).  Note [the blank log](http://imgur.com/hAi0Iou) for file 2.